# In MATLAB, is it possible to redefine `clear` to clear the command window, rather than clear the stored variables?

Tags: matlab, user-defined-functions

Is it possible to redefine `clear` function as `clc`?
I am used to using *nix terminals, so a lot of times, I end up clearing the stored variable when I want to clear the command window.

---

This is my ideal scenario.

`clear` clears the command window, and some other command, maybe `clearvars` clears the defined variables.

Comment: No. Don't do this please.  Just get used to calling `clc` instead of `clear`.  If you're a newcomer to a country, you don't enforce your principles from your previous country onto its citizens.  As such, don't try and force your Unix principles onto MATLAB.

Comment: The problem with overwriting `clear` as `clc` is that when you port your scripts to another machine or import scripts from other machines to your machine, `clear` will be called and does not what it is expected to do.

Comment: @rayryeng and Adriaan: I agree, overloading `clear` isn't a good idea, but it's a valid question about overloading a builtin function. It might not be the best of questions, but IMHO it doesn't deserve all the downvotes. Not knowing that overloading `clear` may cause unwanted consequences isn't the same as "Give me the codez" or other bad questions.

Comment: @StewieGriffin - FWIW, I did not downvote.  This is a good question actually, but not recommended for use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To prevent loss of data, you may create your own `clear.m` which does nothing:

```
function clear(varargin)
   warning('call of clear skipped');
end
```

If you really want to access clear, you have to use `builtin`.

I recommend to keep this file on your search path for some weeks until you are used to the matlab command names.